# How to establish a Two-to-One table relationship (PK-FK-CK)?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, relational-theory, database-agnostic

My question is about DB design and its principles. I am working on a Python application where objects are mapped to database tables.

I have `Projects` and `People` objects, mapped to their respective tables. Then I have `Messages`, also mapped to its own table.

A `message` can belong to either a `person` (people table) or a `project` (projects table) (n-1).

My question:

- Should I create two columns -- `belongs_to_id` and `belongs_to_type` -- for Messages and query to get them? or;
- Should I create an association table for each -- people_have_messages and projects have messages?
- What is the correct way to work in this case scenario?
- How can I create FK constraints and restraints if I go with the first option?

My problem is, as both a Project and a Person (people table) can have the same PK (id), it wouldn't be enough to reference without stating the table and I don't know what exactly to do.

Tables:

```
People:
--------------
ID (PK unique)
Name

Projects:
--------------
ID (PK unique)
Title
Description

Message:
--------------
ID (PK unique)
Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on whether there's a connection between People and Project?

From what you've mentioned, I'd properly go with a:
`Projects -> ProjectsToMessage <- Message`
and 
`People -> PeopleToMesseage <- Message` 
type structure

(your bullet point 2)

Unless there's a releation between Projects and People in which case you might end up with some circular dependency which the database wouldn't like.
However in that case, I would then question whether a Message can be associated to a Project without it going through People.

Comment: Hello @AllanSHansen. Thank you for your message. Projects and People also have a (n-m) relationship, which is handled with a "ProjectsToPeople" table. I suppose having 2 tables to assosciate is a better option. Thanks!

Comment: If People and Projects are connected, do you then need Message on Project? 
Then I'd think a Message could contain a Project FK and a relationship to People to tie it to a specific project; or maybe be connected to the ProjectsToPeople entirely instead?

Comment: That also sounds great. But messages are independent of both Projects and People. I want to keep things "flexible", in case, say a person might moved from project A to B. Therefore, I believe your first suggestion with two separate tables is better to avoid modifying a message's Project_FK when such move occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first option is correct as compared to creating 2 different tables as creating more tables and then using "JOIN" queries on them seems quite costly process for the database(i.e costly in terms of performance)